# How to convert a column of array values

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

How do I convert a column containing array values into separate columns:

Multiple rows, one column

```
{100,67,9}
{100,100}   
{100,100,100}
{100,9}
```

Multiple rows, multiple columns

```
100 67  9
100 100 
100 100 100
100 9
```

Answer (score 2):

A SQL query has a fixed set of columns.  If you know the maximum number, then just extract the values:

```
select t.ar[1] as col1, t.ar[2] as col2, t.ar[3] as col3
from t;
```

If you don't know how many columns will be in the result set, then you would need to use dynamic SQL.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c137021568ff4c07a4a0201ac4f33380) is a db<>fiddle.